# How to remove the splitting area at the bottom of the screen when backgroundtype is BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_BOTH in LWUIT 1.4?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I use LWUIT 1.4 and I like using it because there are look and feel I prefer in it such as the TabbedPane , ... . So the static field `BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGNED_CENTER` is not present in class `Style` in this version. I want to make a LWUIT `Image` ( png ) as a form's background image and I tried using `form.getStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_BOTH);` but the problem is that there is a splitting area occupying just above the menu-bar ( its height is visually equal to the menu-bar's height ) : the background image is displayed clearly without any stains but the splitting area , which is something like the upper part of the image , is at the bottom of the screen just above the menu-bar. So how to remove this splitting area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you are referring to, an image would be helpful and I would also suggest upgrading to 1.5 which is the only supported version right now.

You can always just set a painter to paint your background in any way you like if the style doesn't act the way you want it to.